# iOS, RealityKit, Metal Shader APIs. Determine fragment's distance from the camera

Tags: ios, swift, metal, realitykit, metal-performance-shaders

Using the new Metal Custom Shader API, I've created Grass models that move over time.

Is there a way to determine the distance between the model's fragment and the camera?

I've tried to search through **surface_parameters.uniforms()**.

There are a few potential properties such as **model_to_view**, **projection_to_view** but I don't know what to do further.

Any tips appreciated.

Edit:: Here is the code for the grassGreenShader

```
[[visible]]
void grassGreenShader(realitykit::surface_parameters params)
{
    params.surface().set_base_color(half3(0.094, 0.697, 0.088));
    params.surface().set_opacity(1);
    respondToCameraDistanceShader(params);
}
```

Here is the code to change the base colour of the fragment. This part is wrong:

```
void respondToCameraDistanceShader(realitykit::surface_parameters params)
{
    float3 distanceToCamera = params.geometry().world_position();
    
    if (distanceToCamera.z < 0.3 && distanceToCamera.z > -0.3)
    {
        params.surface().set_opacity(distanceToCamera.z);
        params.surface().set_base_color(half3(0.934, 0.902, 0.355));
    }
}
```

[image: Moving grass]

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Done as requested